# Error: Expected primary-expression before '=='

Tags: c, conditional-statements, syntax-error

I'm trying to work through a book on C and I am stuck on the following error:

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
            if(c >= '0' && c <= '9'){
            ++ndigit[c-'0'];
            }
            else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || == c =='\t'){
                ++nwhite;
            }
                else{
                    ++nother;
                }
    }
```

The compiler is complaining about my comparison of var 'c' and the whitespace chars. 
error: expected primary-expression before '==' token

I haven't written C since school so I am confused as to what is wrong with my syntax. Thanks.

Comment: If you look closely then you have added a unwanted `==` in the third comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

```
 else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || == c =='\t')
```

But it should be

```
else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c =='\t'){
```

Notice the `==` before the last part of the conditional that is removed, in the second snippet.  Even if you haven't written C in a while, it looks like that was a simple typo rather than a misunderstanding of those operators.

Comment: Ha! Even looking at you answer it took me a second to see the extra '=='. I should have taken today off. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || == c =='\t'){
                                  ^^
                                   |
                                   +-- This == should be deleted.
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the == c on the else if line:

else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || **==** c =='\t'){

Answer (score 0):

Well, that `==` in

```
if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || == c =='\t')

                             ^^ Here
```

makes no sense whatsoever. Why did you put it in there?

Answer (score 0):

this is your problem " == c =='\t')" get rid of the == to the left of the c variable

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the line `else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || == c =='\t'){`

It's that `== c == '\t'` at the end that's throwing it off. C doesn't allow you to string together comparisons and, additionally, there's nothing to the left of the `==` (that's what it means by "expected primary expression before ==", it wants something to compare to but there's nothing).

It should be `else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c =='\t'){`